# JSON schema - objects with same datatype

Tags: json, node.js, jsonschema

I generated the following JSON:

```
{
 "someString" : "example",
 "obj1" : {
     "opt1" : 1,
     "opt2" : 1,
     "opt3" : "aaa"
 },
 "obj2" : {
     "opt1" : 55,
     "opt2" : 55,
     "opt3" : "bbb"
 }
}
```

and there will be more of objects(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, ...) with same data type (opt1, opt2, opt3)

now I want to create schema for this but i don't know how to combine all this objects in schema.

EDIT:

I created schema:

```
root: {
    "type" : "object",
    "oneOf" : [
        {
        "properties" : {
            "someString" : { "type" : "string" }
        },
        "patternProperties" : { "^.*$" : { "$ref" : "./schemas/myPatternProperties.json#" } },
        "additionalProperties" : false }
        }
    ]
}
```

and myPatternProperties.json looks:

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "opt1" : { "type" : "number" },
        "opt2" : { "type" : "number" },
        "opt3" : { "type" : "string" },
    }
    "required" : [ "opt1", "opt2", "opt3" ]
}
```

Is there anything wrong because, my generated JSON is still not recognized as this schema type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your problem is to `describe object with a lot of properties with the same type and some naming rules`. To solve that you must specify `patternProperties` section

```
{
    "patternProperties": {
        "^(/[^/]+)+$": { "$ref": "http://some.site.somewhere/entry-schema#" }
}
```

that construction specify `pattern to match` for properties. Example [how to use **patternProperties**](http://json-schema.org/example2.html) Read more at [**specification**](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.5.5)

**UPDATE**

Actually full scheme must be something like that

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "someString": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "patternProperties": {
        "^obj([0-9]+)$": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/objEntity"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [ "someString" ],

    "definitions": {
        "objEntity": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "opt1": { "type": "number" },
                "opt2": { "type": "number" },
                "opt3": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"]
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can split that scheme to more than 1 file, and  change links to type definitions.

Comment: Thanks for reply patterns are what i needed. I created some schema. I think I missed something in this schema because it's still not working correctly.

Comment: Do you get any error message? Your sample data is actually validating fine in JSONBuddy.

Comment: No, I don't get. To check scheme I was using [JSON Schema Validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)

Comment: Im using Node.js and prettyjson module.
Im calling:
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
then
console.log(prettyjson.render(jsonData));

on output I'm getting some fields in incorrect order.
ex.
there is no: opt1, opt2, opt3 but for some reason: opt3, opt1, opt2.
and this order is changing with every run this program.